# replacing special character by tab separation

Tags: bash

I have a file of 200 rows and 1 column
and in each column data appears as
ch:158334782-158335532_Tb_052868_I8

what I want to do is whereever : or - or _ appears it should be replaced by a tab seperation.

the new file should look like this
ch (tab) 158334782 (tab) 158335532 (tab) Tb (tab) 052868 (tab) I8

Any suggestions for a bash script...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **tr**:

```
 tr ':\-_' '\t'  < infile > outfile
```

---

With **sed**:

```
 sed 's/[-_:]/\t/g' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 1):

sed -s 's/[-_]/TAB/'

where TAB is actually a tab